# Python Regex findall dot + newline

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a paragraph containing a certain string using Python. Example:

```
text = """test textract.

new line
test word.

another line."""
```

The following code works:

```
myword = ("word")
re.findall(r'(?<=(\n)).*?'+ myword + r'+.*?(?=(\n))',text)
```

and will return:

```
['test word.']
```

However, if i want to extract ['new line test word.'], none of the following works:

```
re.findall(r'(?<=(\.\n)).*?'+ myword + r'+.*?(?=(\.\n))',text) -> []
re.findall(r'(?<=(\.\n)).|\n*?'+ myword + r'+.|\n*?(?=(\.\n))',text) -> [('', '.\n'), ('', '.\n')]
re.findall(r'(?<=(\.\n)).*|\n*?'+ myword + r'+.*|\n*?(?=(\.\n))',text) -> [('', '.\n'), ('.\n', ''), ('', '.\n'), ('.\n', '')]
```

What should be the right way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are matching a single line, because the newlines are asserted and not matched.

What you could do is use an anchor `^` and repeat all lines that have at least a single non whitespace char and match at least a line that contains `word`

You can also start the pattern with a newline, but then it could miss a first paragraph that is not preceded by a newline.

```
^(?:[^\S\n]*\S.*\n)*.*word.*(?:\n[^\S\n]*\S.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/0kSBaG/1)

```
import re

text = """test textract.

new line
test word.

another line."""

pattern = r"^(?:[^\S\n]*\S.*\n)*.*word.*(?:\n[^\S\n]*\S.*)*"
print(re.findall(pattern, text, re.MULTILINE))
```

Output

```
['new line\ntest word.']
```

Comment: Thanks, tried both answers and yours is more robust, especially in a large body of text.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `re.MULTILINE` and `re.DOTALL` here to analyse the whole text as a single line, and treat newlines as regular characters:

```
import re

text = """\
test textract.

new line
test word.

another line."""

print(re.findall(r'\n+(.*word.*)\n+', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL))
```

Output:

```
['new line\ntest word.\n']
```